# AzureのWeb Appsを端末に持ってくる方法について

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

Visual Studioから、Azureに直接デプロイしたWeb Appsを、別の端末からも開発するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
Azureから別の端末にプロジェクトを持ってくるといったことができるのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dev/products/visual-studio-online.aspx)などのバージョン管理システムを介してソースコードを共有するのが通常のやり方です。
一度サーバーにデプロイしたプログラムをもとに変更を加えるような開発体制が絶対無理とは言いませんが、通常はやりません。